# Django url disspatcher matches the wrong regex

Tags: regex, django

I have created the following urlpatters

```
urlpatterns=[
     url(r'(?P<user_name>[a-zA-Z]+)/$', views.profile_view, 
     kwargs=None, name='userprofile'),
     url(r'(?P<user_name>[a-zA-Z]+)/interests/$',views.interest,name='interests')

]
```

But when I enter the url localhost:8000/mainuser/interest/ it treat it as first url and opens profile_view. It is clearly matching '/'. Help me with this.

Comment: Try `localhost:8000/mainuser/interests/` (note the last `s` in interest)...

Comment: @Alasdair it is not helping. No matter how many slashes i enter after mainuser it matches them all

Answer (score 2):

You should begin your URL patterns with the start of line character `^`. Because you are not including this character the regex for the first pattern matches any URL that ends with 1 or more characters followed by a forward-slash.

```
urlpatterns=[
     url(r'^(?P<user_name>[a-zA-Z]+)/$', views.profile_view, kwargs=None, name='userprofile'),
     url(r'^(?P<user_name>[a-zAZ]+)/interests/$',views.interest,name='interests'),
]
```

Comment: u deserve heaven